# Apache redirect from folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, directory

I have am redirecting my php to not have the .php extension.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The problem I have is I have work.php and a folder called work.

I get this error

```
You don't have permission to access /work/.php on this server.
```

Can you get around this

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off the directory slash using the DirectorySlash directive  At the top of your htaccess or server.config , add the following

```
DirectorySlash off
```

Turning off the directory slash would allow you to access your directory using a trailing slash **/work/** and **/work** (without a trailing slash) will open the file **/work.php** .